# Conditional AND operator don't seem to function properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, conditional-statements

I want to save two data `customerInfo` and `itemInvoiceInfo` one at a time by clicking two different buttons, one for customerInfo and the other for itemInvoiceInfo, the idea is when this two documents are successfully saved in the database, a third button is enabled(becomes clickable) for another action to be taken by the user, the `&&` operator was supposed to make it in such a way that the third button will become active only if `customerSaved` and `itemsSaved` is true(i.e. both have been successfully posted to the database), but what I get is, when I saved any one of the documents, the third button automatically becomes active which is not what I want, it appears my `&&` operator syntax might be wrong, please what could be the issue thanks.

```
const Invoice = () => {
    const[itemSaved, setItemsSaved] = useState(false)
    const[customerSaved, setCustomerSaved] = useState(false)
    const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

 const saveCustomerInvoiceInfo = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/customerInvoiceInfo', 
        {customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNumber, customerState})
            .then((response) => { 
                alert('TRANSACTION CREATED') 
                setCustomerSaved(true)
               // setButtonDisabled(false)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
               // setCustomerSaved(false)
                //setButtonDisabled(true)

        });
    }

    const saveItemsInvoiceDetails = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/itemInvoiceInfo', 
        {productName, costPrice, sellingPrice, unitOfMeasurement, quantity})
            .then((response) => { 
                alert('TRANSACTION CREATED')
                setItemsSaved(true)
               // setButtonDisabled(false)
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
               // setItemsSaved(false)
               // setButtonDisabled(true)

        });
    }

   const disableEnableBtns=()=>{
    if(customerSaved == false && itemSaved == false){
        // const button = document.getElementById('addInvoiceBtn');
        // button.disabled = "disabled"
       
        return  <button type='submit' className='addInvoiceBtn' onClick={handleShowDatePicker} id="addInvoiceBtn" 
        name="addInvoiceBtn" disabled={buttonDisabled}>+ Add</button>
    }else{
        return  <button type='submit' className='addInvoiceBtn' onClick={handleShowDatePicker} id="addInvoiceBtn" 
        name="addInvoiceBtn">+ Add</button>
    }
    
  }

//JSX Code Snippet

return(

        <div className='addInvoice_Date'>
          <div className='invDate'>
            <p>Invoice Date</p>
           {disableEnableBtns()}
          </div>
        </div>

)
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of your conditional statement is fine. The issue is the logic of the conditional isn't following what your intention is. The `disableEnableBtns` function returns the disabled button when *both* `customerSaved` *and* `itemSaved` are false. If only one of them is `true`, it will return an enabled button.

I think you'd want something like this instead:

```
const disableEnableBtns = () => {
    if (customerSaved === true && itemSaved === true) {
        return <button ...>+ Add</button>
    }
    else {
        return <button ... disabled={buttonDisabled}>+ Add</button>
    }
}
```

If you wanted to continue to use `false`s in your conditional, you could do it this way:

```
const disableEnableBtns = () => {
    if (customerSaved === false || itemSaved === false) {
        return <button ... disabled={buttonDisabled}>+ Add</button>
    }
    else {
        return <button ...>+ Add</button>
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW!!, IT WORKED, thanks so much. but the logic to me is still kinda confusing, it appears you reveresed the logic, pls can you explain why it worked this way?

Comment: You want the button to be enabled when both `customerSaved` and `itemSaved` are `true`. This also means that you want to button disabled when only one of them is `false`, so you could have used the `||` operator in your specific implementation. I've edited my answer to include the code snippet of my explanation.

Comment: Ohh!! nice one now I understand the logic, this was really easy to overlook lol, thanks once again.